# How can I move title to the right in collapsible element jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I work on my jquery mobile(1.4.5) project.

I have this html collapsable element:

```
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
        <h4>creaet new layers</h4>
        <fieldset id="newLayerArea" style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;">
            <legend>Layer</legend>
            <button id="btnSaveLayer" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="">save</button>
            <button id="btnCancelLayer" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="">delet</button>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Here how it looks:

[image]

I need to move "creaet new layers" title to the right. while the icon need to stay in it's original position.

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wvVmT/1070/)!!!

How can I move title "creaet new layers" to the right?

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with jquery:

You need to use following css

```
fieldset#newLayerArea legend{
  text-align: right;
}
```

in code:

```
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
    <h4>creaet new layers</h4>
    <fieldset id="newLayerArea" style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;">
        <legend style="text-align:right">Layer</legend>
        <button id="btnSaveLayer" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="">save</button>
        <button id="btnCancelLayer" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="">delet</button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: can I put it as style in HTML element?

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying in your question, you need this for JQM 1.4.5 - here is it:

```css
.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle.ui-btn {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page-one">
    <div data-role="content">
      <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h4>creaet new layers</h4>
        <fieldset id="newLayerArea" style="border: solid 1px #6b6b6b;">
          <legend>Layer</legend>
          <button id="btnSaveLayer" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-b" onclick="">שמירה</button>
          <button id="btnCancelLayer" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="">ביטול</button>
        </fieldset>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But be aware, in your Fiddle you are referencing an older JQM version.

```
.ui-collapsible-heading>a>span {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```